In Figma how can I create a color variable or token that is a mix of two other variables/tokens?
When creating a color pallet you often have different shades, tones and tint of the primary and secondary colors. To do so in all the guides they create each one manually. That is ok to do once but what if you want to play around with colors and change the primary? You would have to change each tone, shade and tint tokens/variables. That is way too much of a hassle. Can't I just make a variable/token be a combination of a primary color and whatever other color I want? That way I would only change my primary and all the tones, tints, and tokens would change automatically.
I am new to figma but this seems like a no brainer need and implementation and it is frustrating that I can't even find mention of this anywhere.
